# Is there a way to view all non [skyrim] and non [modern-warfare-3] questions?

Tags: support

Other than adding the 2 tags [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) and [modern-warfare-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modern-warfare-3) to Ignored tags and skimming past them, is there a method of seeing everything not tagged with those two items? Can you view all items not tagged with multiple tags or even a single tag?

I see the search does support the - operator on a tag, but I still have to search on a term along with it.

Just asking this out of curiosity, I don't really mind the questions and the overload of [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim) stuff, but I just want to see what else I may be missing out on.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't have to use a search term. `*` will match everything.

> [`* -[skyrim] -[modern-warfare-3]`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=*%20-%5bskyrim%5d%20-%5bmodern-warfare-3%5d)

works in this case.

Comment: Didn't even consider that the * would work. Thanks!

Comment: Datalog won't be pleased.

Comment: Is there a keyword for all ignored tags?

Comment: @CyberSkull No, there isn't one